# how to use React.useState(window.innerWidth) in server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

React.useState(window.innerWidth) is failing due to server-side rendering as there is no window object in server-side.
How can I fix it?
I have been trying code in this link 
https://blog.logrocket.com/developing-responsive-layouts-with-react-hooks/

Comment: You may pass in a default value using the ternary operator: `React.useState(typeof window !== 'undefined'? window.innerWidth: 800)`.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the case when the code is run on server-side with a conditional check to see if `window` exists. A possible implementation for your use case could be: `React.useState(typeof window !== 'undefined'? window.innerWidth: 800)`

One thing worth mentioning is that unless the client sends its `window.innerWidth` to the server along with the page request, the server can only use a default value like above (or guess from user-agent maybe). So there can be a slight flicker on the client screen if the layout derived on the server-side is very different from the layout derived on the client-side.

That's why I always prefer using CSS for responsive layout over JavaScript when doing server-side rendering.

Comment: "That's why I always prefer using CSS for responsive layout over JavaScript when doing server-side rendering." do you have any css idea for this problem ?i am using a class that i add conditionally. only for mobile

Comment: Could you always attach that class and use media query to conditionally apply styles?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: Then just use JavaScript. It can be a totally valid use case.